# converting to minutes

Tags: homogeneous-equation

I'm trying to answer a question in minutes but I just can't seem to be able to eliminate all the other units.

((B×D)/(M×PWR))×60

B = 500Wh,
D = 80% of B,
M = 12.505kg,
PWR = 55W/kg

I should be able to cancel out Watts as one is a numerator and the other a denominator. D is unitless? which leaves me with lets say

(400h/12.505kgx55kg)x60

I can't just cancel out kg as they are both denominators... right? so that's where I'm stuck. if I can't cancel kg and just leave me with **hx60 and end up with an answer I can put into minutes.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Your original equation is: $$\displaystyle \frac{Wh}{kg \times\frac{W}{kg}}$$

Cancelling W gives: $$\displaystyle \frac{h}{kg \times\frac{1}{kg}}$$

$$\boxed{\text{Remember that cancelling W from the denominator leaves} \frac{1}{kg} \text{and not kg}}$$

Simplifying the denominator:  $$\displaystyle \frac{h}{{kg} \times\frac{1}{kg}} \rightarrow \frac{h}{1} $$

$$\therefore h$$

Comment: Thank you Shane, your answer has cleared up my confusion